# How does concurrency using immutable/persistent types and data structures work?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability

I've read a lot about functional languages recently. Since those use only immutable structures they claim that concurrency issues are greatly improved/solved. I'm having some serious trouble understanding how this can actually be delivered in a real-life context. Let's assume we have a web server with one thread listening on a port (well, IO is another thing i have difficulty wrapping my head around but let's just ignore that for now); On any connection attempt a socket is created and passed to a newly created thread which does some work with it and, depending on the received communications, may apply changes to a big list/data structure which is global to the server application. So, how does this list access work then in order for all threads having a consistent view of the list (or at least in order to have all changes made by one thread applied to the list as soon as the thread dies in a correct manner)?

My problems understanding are:

- Obviously any thread can get a unchangeable "snapshot" of the list to work on. However, after "changing" the contents by creating a new version of the list with the changes applied, we are still left with every thread having their own version of the list. How are those merged back together?
- Another method might consist of using traditional locking mechanisms like mutex/cond or go-like-channels. However, how would you even create such a thing when all variables are immutable?
- I've heard about STM, however that cannot deal with side effects (i.e. if the list would also transparently backup the data to a file or db)

So how would you model such a thing in a functional language?

Comment: here is a good talk about the underlying concepts http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey

Comment: Already seen that one 2 times but unfortunately, still don't get it. The biggest problems with functional programming are 1) most people have learned and trained imperative languages 2) functional languages requires thinking in a different way 3) there are no resources teaching functional programming which are specifically targeted at the 99% (=the imperative programming people) except for incredibly trivial examples

Comment: Thats where I'm coming from as well and it's not easy. I would start from trying to answer why threads need to read the side effects of other threads. I've just begun my journey and thats why I wouldn't try to answer, I'm sure there are much more qualified persons here to answer this though :-)

Comment: @BillAskaga I don't think targeting learning material at people coming from imperative languages is very helpful. It is bound to be full of false equivalencies and bad parallels. (However, there's also a lack of FP teching material for non-FP programmers in general.)

Comment: @kqr I agree that direct parallels should be avoided since both paradigms are quite different. However, imperative examples "translated" to a functional equivalent showing functional style best practices would be very helpful since it could show imperative programmers where and in which way they have to change their thought patterns.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Immutable values have several applications for which they are well suited. The concurrent/parallel processing is just one of them that got more important recently. The following is really the most basic digest from experience and many books and talks about the subject. You may need to dive into some eventually.

The main example you show here is about managing global state, so it cannot be done purely "immutably". However, even here there are very good reasons to use immutable data structures. Some of those from top of my head:

- try - catch behaves much better, because you do not modify shared object that may be left modified half-way, with immutable values, it automatically keeps the last consistent state
- reducing changing state to just multicore safe "compare-and-swap" operations on very limited set of global variables (ideally one), completely eliminates deadlocks
- free passing of data structures without any defensive copying that is quite often case of mysterious bugs when forgotten (many times defensive copies are created in both calling and called functions, because developers start to incline to "better safe than sorry" after a couple of debugging sessions)
- much easier unit testing, because many functions operating on immutable values are side-effect free
- usually easier serialization and more transparent comparison semantics 
  much easier debugging and taking (logging) a current snapshot of the system state even asynchronously

Back to your question though.

In the most trivial case the global state in this case is often modelled using one mutable reference at the top holding onto an immutable data structure.

The reference is updated only by CAS atomic operation.

The immutable data structure is transformed by a side-effect free functions and when all transformations are done the reference is swapped atomically.

If two threads/cores want to swap simultaneously new values got from the same old one, the one doing that first wins the other does not succeed (CAS semantics) and needs to repeat the operation (depends on the transformation, either updating the current one with the new value, or transforming the new value from the beginning). This may seem wasteful, but the assumption here is that redoing some work is often cheaper than permanent locking/synchronization overhead.

Of course this can be optimized e.g. by partitioning independent parts of immutable data structures to further reduce potential collisions by having several references being updated independently.

Access to the data structure is lock-free and very fast and always gives a consistent response. Edge cases like when you send an update and another client receives older data afterwards is to be expected in any system, because of network requests can get out of order too...

STM is useful quite rarely and usually you are better of to use atomic swaps of data structure containing all values from references you would use in STM transaction.

Comment: Very good answer. Provides a lot of insight about things which are thoroughly ignored (or badly explained) in most tutorials about functional programming.

Comment: Thank you. I've been searching the interwebs for days now to find an answer to the problem of merging with regards to immutable data. Most any resources would thoughtlessly repeat the mantra "[...] is thread-safe and therefore helps with concurrency" without going into the much harder problem of merging back the changes.

Comment: If we take an example of some sort of map-like data structure. If this map-like structure was immutable, and we wanted it to be concurrent as well, wouldn't this mean that each key-value pair would have to be an independent CAS operation during concurrent writes?

Comment: And then combining that aspect with a sort of batched up modifications that needs to occur via a transactional snapshot, then once a transaction is committed, we would need to resolve potential conflicts between each possible key-value pair. What would the API look like in this case?

Comment: In doing this, you would also need some sort of transaction manager. So given an immutable data structure, there would be need a way to create a single "concurrent" representation of it, and then supply references to it for multiple processes.